# Multiple resolution support on Samsung TV

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to get my app to display at higher resolution than 540x960, but not having luck.

I have added

```
'resolutions' : ['540p','720p'],
```

to app.json, and added css files app/stylesheets/540p/Main.css, app/stylesheets/720p/Main.css

This alone did not do the trick, it is still displaying at 540x960 (on a 20120 model TV that supports up to 1080p)

I have also noticed that in config.xml, there is a width and height specified.  I'm not sure what to do there to support multiple resolutions, or if that is even involved.

Thanks for any insights....

Here are a few relevant links:

http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/apps_framework/manage_scenes/add_scene.html

http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/7e2b7fa90012098b?forumID=f69ed7370fdb3193

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_3.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/AppsFramework_APIs/Framework_API/Core_API/sf.env/getResolution

Answer (score 1):

the Emulator 3.5  doesn't support 1920x1080 resolution. But if you are following the instructions in http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/apps_framework/manage_scenes/add_scene.html  then you app is Multiple resolution support!, then when you test your app on the tv, will run. You need to be carefull with the css, lock this and use http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/ux_guideline20/06_application_layout/application_screen_resolution.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the TV Set has 1080p support - it doesn't mean that Smart TV applications will work at this resolution too:

- In Samsung 2010 there was only one resolution: 960x540px
- In Samsung 2011 you have two: 960x540px, 1280x720px
- And the Samsung 2012: 1280x720px

For 2012 I've never checked if you can set FullHD but maybe

You can change application resolution only in one way - changing the value in config.xml file.

So when you want to have support for all models you need make two layouts at least: one for 540p (2010model) and one for 720p (2011,2012 models).

There is no option to automatically "stretch" the app to another resolution.